# Configuring oauthRedirectURI dynamically in SalesForceMobile SDK for Login in android

Tags: mobilesdk

I am working on an app SalesForce SDK for login in android. We are using **'com.salesforce.mobilesdk:SalesforceSDK:8.+'**.

I am able to configure the login url dynamically through code but not able to configure **oauthRedirectURI** dynamically through code.

I am using the below code to configure

```
LoginServerManager.LoginServer selectedServer = new LoginServerManager.LoginServer("Name", "login url", false);
SalesforceSDKManager.getInstance().getLoginServerManager().setSelectedLoginServer(selectedServer);
```

Can some one help us how to configure the **oauthRedirectURI** dynamically for Android.

Answer (score 0):

There is no reason your app should ever need to do this.  Your app should have exactly 1 consumer key and redirect uri pair.  That single key and uri identifies your app and does not need to be changed no matter what login server you specify.